# Strange Search Query Appearing on Google Index - "/?q=Save+Us+From+Berlusconi"

Tags: plugins, search, seo, google-search

Strange.

Stripping my site URL, and searching for the term "/?q=Save+Us+From+Berlusconi"  on Google shows up this blog post written way back in 2009: http://www.seroundtable.com/archives/021647.html

My site is facing something similar.

What should I do? Is this really a bug from Google? It looks like Berlusconi is the prime minister of Italy; however my site has nothing to do with political stuffs. I see there are a couple of threads in Google forum -- older ones -- that talk about this strange query indexed on Google.

Example query: http://www.google.com/search?q=%22websites+to+automatically+post+blog+post+on+twitter%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Check the second URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a WordPress question … yet.

There are two ways to handle this.

1. **Don’t do anything.** One more indexed page will not harm your site’s karma. This is not spam. Someone has has probably created a link to your site with this query string to trick the auto-complete tool on Google. The link may be gone now, but Google doesn’t forget. So what?
2. **Fix your search.** I tested the search string on the website from your profile and I got many “results”. That’s a problem. You serve exactly the same set of articles for every search. This is not useful for your visitors. Plus, if some bad guy creates a file with 10.000 links to different searches you get a serious [duplicate content](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66359) problem. Install a good search plugin – I suggest [Relevanssi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/) – and make sure to show only real results.

Comment: Thank you. This makes a lot of sense now. I have been using Google Custom search, and I assume this may be conflicting with the default WordPress search. I might have to look into the search.php file once again, and see if I could make anything out of it.

I'll definitely try out Relevanssi to see if that could put a limit on search.